# Please verify the proof for percentage of error in power factor measurement

Tags: power-factor-correction, formal-verification

I am constructing an ac wattmeter for my school project, one of the objective is to achieve discrepancy of result(power factor) that is within 5% as compare to the actual measurement result obtained from wattmeter in market. This is done by setting a timer to measure current and voltage zero cross detection. As an example, the picture below show the rising edge of voltage(yellow) and current(blue) square wave as output by zero cross detection. The result is then compute by microcontroller.

[image]

After some consideration, isn't this is actually quite ambiguous to say "5%" without without specify at what phase angle of the measurement load. So I'm trying to show percentage of error increases for fixed amount of error as the actual phase angle of the load increases. Please verify if this make sense.

discrepancy=(actual result-measure result/actual result)

Assuming the error in phase angle difference is very small
$$Actual result=cos\theta,d\theta=error,measurement result=cos(\theta+d\theta)$$

then discrepancy can be written as
$$\frac{cos\theta-cos(\theta+d\theta)}{cos\theta}=-\frac{cos(\theta+d\theta)-cos\theta}{d\theta.cos\theta}.d\theta=tan\theta.d\theta$$

Consider the angle difference is very small and fixed at different phase angle, this show that the percentage error is proportional to $$tan\theta$$
since tan is an increasing function, the error increase as phase angle increase.

Example of measuring the power factor of a load of impedance 1+10i is more prone to error as compare to a load of 1+0.1i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Please verify if this make sense.*

Voltage can usually be relied upon to be a sinewave but, current can be awful and trying to compute phase angle to deliver power factor is not going to work except on ideal loads such as inductors, capacitors and resistors.

A TV or appliance usually has some form of bridge rectification and, although modern devices have a more reasonable power factor footprint, there can still be several degrees of mismatch between actual zero crossing current and ideal-load zero crossing current.

If you want to compute power factor in the presence of loads which create highly harmonic currents, you should compute true power (using v × i), RMS voltage and RMS current then solve for power factor: -

$$v_{instantaneous}\times i_{instantaneous} \text{ (watts)} = V_{RMS}\times I_{RMS}\times \cos\phi$$

Example of voltage and current taken by a conventional appliance such as a TV: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/TVs-voltage-and-current-waveforms-versus-Time_fig1_337011835). Basically, the advice is to research what you are hoping to measure and don't assume all loads are at all sinewave shaped. Here are some more images: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-current-and-voltage-waveforms-of-nine-types-of-appliance_fig11_324082872).